# Locating Element with same class in Selenium using c#

Tags: selenium, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to access ABC. I know that simple By.ClassName("bb") will not work here. How else can I access this content.

```
<body>
 <div id="Frame">
 <div class="bb"></div>
 <div class="bb">ABC</div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below css selector to get the value of "ABC".

```
.bb:nth-child(2)
```

Comment: NOTE: this only works if the element is *always* the second element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ["XPath"](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp) Expression to find or locating your element.

Example : `element = findElement(By.xpath("Your xpath expression");`

**For your XML use following line.**

`element = findElement(By.xpath("/body/div/div[@class='bb'][node()]");`

Comment: Why not add the "ABC" text as a search criteria in the XPath? That seems like it would be optimal. Your current answer doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this in the search using XPath but I am not an XPath expert. I can give you a solution using CSS Selectors. Basically you grab all the DIVs with class bb and then search their text to find the desired text.

```
String searchText = "ABC";
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> divs = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.bb"));
foreach (IWebElement div in divs)
{
    if (div.Text == searchText)
    {
        break; // exit the for and use the variable 'div' which contains the desired DIV
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This doesn't seem to work. My divs count always stays 0.

Comment: Is the HTML above correct? If so, this should work unless it's in an IFRAME or hidden or something.